# How do you pull the password file/hash on a locked debian computer using John the Ripper or likewise?

Tags: debian, john-the-ripper

Currently using John the Ripper to test some of our network passwords, however, we do have a server that is completely locked up and we do not know the password for... Issue is, cant restart/turn off the old thing because its running some applications that our workplace needs up 99.9% of the time, as well as some databases that are actively updated...

Answer (score 0):

If you're locked out of root you're basically asking to hack into your system while having a normal user account. I don't think anyone can help you unless your system is running some software components which can be exploited including the kernel itself.

Looks like restarting/shutting it down (to boot from a different media/removing a disk) is the only option.

Comment: ;-;
I dont even have the normal user, I just have a different computer. So sad.

Comment: This leaves you with even fewer options. At some point you'll have to reboot it anyways (for maintenance tasks), so the earlier you do that, the better.

Comment: Yeah thats a fair point. Sucks that I have to tell the man 'Hey we gotta do it', but it is what it is really. 

Thanks a ton for your help though, now I know!